# Having trouble with the divsion of 2 numbers in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The program I am doing is a basic calculator. The first input tells what operation to do(1 for addition 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, 4 for division, and -1 to exit) I have been able to do the addition, subtraction and multiplication of two numbers but I am having trouble with the division of two numbers. It always gives me a funky output. For example, if I put inputs 20 and 5 after the 1st input of 4 it gives out 0/20->20

```
# CPSC 2500 Winter 2023
# Name:
# Date:

# Compile on Linux using: gcc -g -fno-pie -no-pie ./calc.s -o calc

.bss # block starting symbol, contains allocated but not yet initialized memory
num: # num will hold a 64 bit integer provided by the user
    .skip 8

.data
addstr: # C-style formatting for calling printf()
    .asciz "%d + %d -> %d\n"

minusstr: # C-style formatting for calling printf()
    .asciz "%d - %d -> %d\n"

mutiplystr: # C-style formatting for calling printf()
    .asciz "%d * %d -> %d\n"

dividestr: # C-style formatting for calling printf()
    .asciz "%d / %d -> %d\n"

.text
.global main

getint: # get integer from user
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $0, %rdi
    movq $num, %rsi
    movq $8, %rdx
    syscall # get user input from STDIN

    movq $num, %rdi
    call atoi # convert user input from string to integer
    ret

printint: # print result of addition
    mov $addstr, %rdi
    mov %r14, %rsi
    mov %rax, %rdx
    mov %r15, %rcx
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret

printintminus: # print result of subtraction
    mov $minusstr, %rdi
    mov %r14, %rsi
    mov %rax, %rdx
    mov %r15, %rcx
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret


printinttimes: # print result of multiplication
    mov $mutiplystr, %rdi
    mov %r14, %rsi
    mov %rax, %rdx
    mov %r15, %rcx
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret

printintdiv: # print result of division
    mov $dividestr, %rdi   # Format string
    mov %rax, %rsi         # Quotient
    mov %r15, %rdx         # Divisor
    mov %r14, %rcx         # Dividend
    call printf
    ret




end: # terminate program
    mov $60, %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall

main:
    call getint 
    mov %rax, %r13
    cmpq $-1, %r13
    je end
    call getint
    mov %rax, %r15
    call getint
    mov %r15, %r14
    cmpq $1, %r13
    je addtwonums
    cmpq $2, %r13
    je subtwonums
    cmpq $3, %r13
    je mutiplytwonums
    cmpq $4, %r13
    je dividetwonums
    jmp main


addtwonums:
    add %rax, %r15
    call printint
    jmp main

subtwonums:
    sub %rax, %r15
    call printintminus
    jmp main

mutiplytwonums:
    imul %rax, %r15
    call printinttimes
    jmp main

dividetwonums:
    cqo
    cmpq $0, %r15
    je divisionbyzero
    idiv %r15
    call printintdiv
    jmp main

divisionbyzero:
    mov $dividestr, %rdi
    mov $0, %rsi  # Dividend (always zero in this case)
    mov $0, %rdx  # Divisor (already zero)
    call printf
    jmp main
```

Comment: For signed division, you want `cqo` ; `idiv` to sign-extend RAX into RDX:RAX.  If you zero-extend by just zeroing RDX, negative numbers will get treated as unsigned, as if you'd added 2^64.  But it sounds like you have a different bug.  Single-step your code in a debugger to see what register values you have after parsing integer inputs, and if they still have those values when you reach your `dividetwonums` function.  Also, use triple backticks to format your code.

Comment: PS: if you are using the C library anyway, why do you use read syscall with `atoi` instead of `scanf`?

Comment: You are passing the arguments to `printf` in the wrong order. Your format string is `"%d / %d -> %d\n"` so you need dividend, divisor, quotient. Also your code is dividing the second number by the first and you don't save the dividend anywhere. You want `mov %rax, %r14` not `mov %r15, %r14`